# Can I land Headshots with Ana?

Tags: overwatch

Ana is Overwatch's Support sniper who shoots people to heal them.

Like Widowmaker, Ana has a scope. Unlike Widowmaker, Ana doesn't seem to get any benefit from scoping, other than the zoom.

Can Ana's biotic rifle shots land headshots? I notice that she doesn't have a "Critical Headshots" stat tracker either...

Comment: Given that her damage is a Damage-Over-Time, I'm not sure if "headshot" is meaningful.

Comment: Scoping makes her weapon hitscan instead of projectile, though, which is nice.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm assuming you mean critical hits on headshots. There's no explanation other than no - she will not get a critical hit when landing a headshot.

Source: http://overwatch.gamepedia.com/Ana

Comment: You should also add to your answer the comment that @Decency made, that scoping makes the weapon hitscan instead of projectile. While you still don't get headshots, the differentiation is important in some cases, and your aiming should be slightly different.

Comment: @DoktorJ Well the question was "Can I land Headshots with Ana?". There's literally no other way to say it other than "no".

Answer (score 8):

> Unlike Widowmaker, Ana doesn't seem to get any benefit from scoping, other than the zoom.

There is actually a benefit to scoping in with Ana. While she cannot score headshots, her projectile speed changes based on zoom. While scoped in, her projectiles are hitscan and *cannot* be deflected by Genji. When not scoped in, her projectiles have travel time and *can* be deflected.

[(Hitscan vs projectile source)](http://overwatch.gamepedia.com/Ana#Biotic_Rifle)

[(Genji reflect for scoped and non-scoped source)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=No2mH5_c494)

Comment: I'm guessing the Genji inability to reflect is a bug. He can deflect Widowmaker's scoped shots which are hitscan.

Comment: That or related to the dot nature of the shot that interacts weirdly with his deflect. It does seem like a bug for now, though it's likely in place to stop him accidentally deflecting friendly Ana heal shots.

Comment: Perhaps, though that wouldn't explain why he can reflect her unscoped shots but not her scoped ones. Even though it is hitscan my expectation would be that it hits him, so it's treated as a hostile shot, and gets reflected, but maybe somewhere in there is where the bug is.